# Help on error in your cart HTML button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently developing my website for addcart. Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="rmr" id="payment1" value="3" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="payment1" value="1" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="payment2" value="2" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="payment4" value="4" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
```

Already I created a page named unlock payment. On that page the customer add the addcart to basket.

What I want is additionally to add that three buttons for YOUR CART. That radio button indicates delivery methods named normal, royal, postal. If customer clicks those buttons that amount must be added with get YOURCART and displayed Totally.. it is dynamical no need to store it in a DB.

How could I do and what query I need to implement it. Is there any need to use AJAX call?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".cart :input[name='rmr']").click(function() {
         updatePayment($(this).val());
         if (!!$(this).attr("checked") == true) {
             $("#finalamount").html( parseInt($("#totalamount").val(), 10) * parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Please use the code button that looks like: `{}` instead of removing the angle brackets from your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you know your current totalamount first, then whenever any one of the input boxes is clicked it gets updated. For example:

```
var totalAmount = 10.0; //Set from the database
function updateAmount(var additionalCost)
{
  document.getElementById("finalamount").innerHTML = totalAmount + additionalCost;
}
```

Each click on a radiobutton wold call updateAmount with their respective additional costs.

Comment: nice idea you gave me but it does not working sir what should i do

Comment: What doesnt work? Whats the error message you get? Also, you might want to rewrite it to jQuery, since you seem to use that.

Comment: error in the sense nothing changed. when ever i click that button there is no action

Comment: you plz vist that page http://spsmobile.co.uk/make-payment.php you may see the delivery details with radio buttons.